# svchost.exe using tcp https protocol on local port 50721?

Tags: https, port, tcp, svchost, stealth

I am noticing a ton of system processes running on my network from a specific computer and there are TCP https packets being sent. Here are a few IPs I notice. Is this normal? Ukraine addresses giving no results back when tracing them ip-lookup

[image]

[image]

I was told to come post here because this is where this question belonged? I was told my computer is infected with a virus and disconnect it now though this computer has been on the network for a long time now. The user reported claims of harassment from a conflict in a game and since been experiencing issues and receiving threats.

Since seeing this computer infected, I had taken it off the network, whiped it clean with a fresh copy of Windows 10 using Rufus and a copy of the ISO from Microsoft download page, installed Kaspersky then began updating the machine. These screenshots posted are roughly 1 hour or so of uptime. Obviously my security measures are not strong enough I think maybe the router is infected or another computer on the network so it automatically infects this targeted PC once back online?

Answer (score 2):

The port `50721` is totally irrelevant: every HTTPS connection to remote HTTPS port `443` is made from a random local port between `49152` and `65535`; the *dynamic*, *private* or *ephemeral* ports.

> Port numbers are assigned in various ways, based on three ranges:
> System Ports (`0-1023`), User Ports (`1024-49151`), and the Dynamic and/or
> Private Ports (`49152-65535`); the difference uses of these ranges is
> described in [[RFC 6335]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6335).

Then, they are not connections from "a ton of system processes running", but connections in a `TIME_WAIT` state, i.e. *the socket is waiting after close to handle packets still in the network*. It's completely normal that they belong to the `[System Process]`, PID `0`.

You'll soon get more of these with the fresh Windows 10 install with virus protection from Kaspersky Lab. Most of these IP addresses are in `62.128.100.0/23`, netname `LINX-MOW-DIA-KASPERSKY-LAB`, belonging to **Kaspersky Lab**. Those connections were to Kaspersky's update servers or similar.

Comment: how come someone from the last post I made said I have virus and to remove right away?